# Proving and disproving First Order Logic statements in $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 77)

> 7. Are these statements true or false? The universe of discourse is $\mathbb{N}$.
>
> (c) $\forall x\exists y(x - 2y = 0)$.
>
> (d) $\forall x(x < 10 \to \forall y(y < x \to y < 9))$.

**Disproof of (c):**

I need to show the negation of $\forall x\exists y(x < 10 \to \forall y(y < x \to y < 9))$  is true.

- $\lnot(\textsf{1 is even})$

  - Assume $1 - 2b = 0$

    - 1 = 2b
    - 1 is even
    - $\lnot$(1 is even)
    - $\bot$
  - $1 - 2b \neq 0$
  - $\forall y(1 - 2y \neq 0)$, $\quad\to \forall\textsf{ Introduction}$
  - $\exists x\forall y(x - 2y \neq 0)$, $\quad\to \exists\textsf{ Introduction}$

**Proof of (d):**

- Assume $a < 10$, $\quad a \in \mathbb{N}$

  - Assume b < a, $\quad b \in \mathbb{N}$

    - b < 10, by transitivity of $<$
    - $\vdots$
    - $b < 9$
  - $b < a \to b < 9$, $\quad\to \textsf{Introduction}$
  - $\forall y(y < a \to y < 9)$, $\quad\to \forall\textsf{ Introduction}$
- $a < 10 \to \forall y(y < a \to y < 9)$
- $\forall x(x < 10 \to \forall y(y < x \to y < 9)$, $\quad\to \forall\textsf{ Introduction}$

**Questions:**

Are the proof skeleton of **c** and disproof of **d** correct ?
How can I fill the gaps in point **c** ?

EDIT: taking inspiration in Daniel Schepler's comment, I revised point (d).

**Proof of (d):**

- Assume $a < 10$, $\quad a \in \mathbb{N}$

  - Assume $b < a$, $\quad b \in \mathbb{N}$

    - $a<9+1$
    - $a<9+1 \to a <= 9$
    - $a<=9$
    - $b<a \land a<=9$
    - $b < a \land a <= 9 \to b < 9$
    - $b < 9$
  - $b < a \to b < 9$, $\quad\to \textsf{Introduction}$
  - $\forall y(y < a \to y < 9)$, $\quad\to \forall\textsf{ Introduction}$
- $a < 10 \to \forall y(y < a \to y < 9)$
- $\forall x(x < 10 \to \forall y(y < x \to y < 9)$, $\quad\to \forall\textsf{ Introduction}$

Comment: For a disproof a counterexample will suffice; thus, showing that $3 -2y=0$ has no solution in $\mathbb N$ is enough for (c).

Comment: Does Velleman specify all of the permissible rules of inference?  I was under the impression that his book didn't have formal rules of inference, and more was about writing convincing arguments.  If so, I think the question would be, would the above arguments be convincing to people you believe to have relevant knowledge?  I could be wrong though, I haven't studied Velleman's book.

Comment: Thank you, @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. It is helpful what you point out.

Comment: There is an appendix called “Summary of Proof Techniques” in the book, @Doug Spoonwood. Universal and Existential Instantiation are mentioned there, for example. Also, in a section called “Proofs Involving Quantifiers”. I appreciated your input.

Comment: For (d), my line of argument would probably combine a fact $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{N}, x < y + 1 \rightarrow x \le y$ and a fact $\forall x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}, x < y \rightarrow y \le z \rightarrow x < z$.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood is correct that the focus of How To Prove It is on writing proofs in English, not formal logical derivations.  Of course, steps in English proofs often correspond to steps in formal logical derivations, so the book does mention the names of some rules of formal logic.  Also, this exercise comes from Chapter 2, and the discussion of proofs doesn't start until Chapter 3.  This question is not asking for a proof, it is simply asking if the statements are true or false.  By the way, in (d) there is no $\exists y$; it is just $\forall x(x < 10 \ldots)$.

Comment: @DanVelleman Ah, so you're using the concept of a proof such that it's an argument that convinces the reader that it could get formalized by a suitable expert acquainted with formalizing such arguments, correct?

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood I would say it a little differently.  I'd say a proof is an argument that convinces a mathematically literate reader.  The steps that convince mathematically literate readers often correspond to the steps that a suitable expert would use to formalize the argument.  But many mathematically literate readers know nothing about formalization, and don't think about it when judging the correctness of a proof.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @Daniel Schepler. Is my revised proof of d closer to what you thought ?

Comment: I really appreciate your input and marvellous book, @Dan Velleman. The exercise only asks whether these statements are true or false; however, I tried to prove them in order to understand a little more. One question: could you explain why you say that there is no $\exists y$? I cannot see exactly what you mean.

Comment: @F. Zer I just meant that at the beginning of your post, when you quoted part (d) of the problem, you put in an extra $\exists y$ that is not in the book.  I have deleted it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, @Dan Velleman.